# Is there any documentation for the Metro UI styles?

Tags: css, microsoft-metro, metro-ui-css

I really like the Metro UI and love the fact that it is becoming so popular now days. I was wondering if there is some documentation or guidelines probably from Microsoft itself that contain things like what should be the size of tiles, how much should be the padding and margin etc of different elements.

A document that we devs can use to create a better consistent UI independent of the designers. I searched around but there only seem to be scattered design preferences by various people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[User Experience Design Guidelines for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/fa00461b-abe1-41d1-be87-0b0fe3d3389d(v=vs.105).aspx)

[User Experience Design Guidelines for Web](http://metroui.org.ua/)

Related:
[Windows Phone UI and Design Language](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX10/CL14) on Channel 9 (video)